# Accessing route::resource using https in Laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, resources, laravel

To force HTTPS  on a named route, the Laravel docs say do the following:

```
Route::get('foo', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

Now, on my first Laravel app, I have been using resource controllers. I don't think I will be using them for my second app, going on what I have since read, but for now they sit happily in my router.php file.

I wanted to force the back office part of my app to use HTTPS. So, my opening gambit was as follows:

```
Route::resource('backoffice', array('https','BackofficeController'));
```

Laravel didn't like the array.

So, instead I thought I would try putting at the next parameter:

```
Route::resource('backoffice', 'BackofficeController', 'https'));
```

But the next parameter needs to be an array. I could find no documentation on this, but I converted it to array. It still didn't work.

```
Route::resource('backoffice', 'BackofficeController', array('https')));
```

I even tried:

```
Route::resource('backoffice', 'BackofficeController', array('https'=>true)));
```

However, that failed too. So, how do I force a resource to use https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::filter('forceHttps', function($req){
    if (! Request::secure()) {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::getRequestUri());
    }
});

Route::group(['before' => 'forceHttps'], function(){
    Route::resource('backoffice', 'BackofficeController');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I tried this, and it does help but its still not working. If I browse to hxxp://mysite/backoffice it does now redirect to hxxps://mysite.backoffice, however, I still get a 404 error.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked ADD COMMENT before I had finished. As I explained in my edit above, If I browse to hxxp://mysite/backoffice it does now redirect to hxxps://mysite.backoffice, however, I still get a 404 error.

Comment: What is the URL that `Redirect::secure(...)` outputs? Do you develop on local virtual host? If so, what's the URL? I use `http://projectname.loc` for my projects. Tested this solution and it works.

Comment: The url being generated is correct. Without the filter, and tested on a local virtual host, if I type the following I get to my backoffice: `http://mysite.local/backoffice`. However, if I apply the filter, and try the above link, it gets redirected to the following url: `https://mysite.local/backoffice` and generates a 404 error.

Comment: Looks like server configuration problem here.

Comment: Yes you are quite right. Ironically, this was precisely why I wanted to test for SSL. I copied the setup to my production server (not yet live) and it works fine there. Using environments I can disable SSL on the local machine, at least until I've got SSL configured properly. So I am happy. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a filter function like the one Andreyco suggested, which seems fine, you could do something similar to this:

```
//Andreyco's filter
Route::filter('forceHttps', function($req){
if (! Request::secure()) {
    return Redirect::secure(Request::getRequestUri());
}
});
//backoffice group routing
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backoffice', 'before' => 'forceHttps'), function()
{
    Route::any('/',                'App\Controllers\BOindexController@index');
    Route::resource('otherBackOfficeURI', 'App\Controllers\OtherBOController');
    //other routes & controllers here...
});
```

This way, everything starting with site.tld/backoffice will go through the https filter (and most probably through a isAdmin filter) and then check inner function route rules. I think this will be more convenient.